# nginx-proxy doesn't work with swagger-ui docker container 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, swagger, swagger-ui, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I would like to change my local urls from 'localhost:port' to project related urls. Every other container in the stack (Node server etc.) works but only swagger container gives error 502 Bad Gateway.

I add this to my /etc/hosts file:

```
 127.0.0.1       my-api-doc.local
```

here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
   version: '3'
   services: 
     api_doc:
       image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
       environment:
         - "VIRTUAL_HOST=my-api-doc.local"
         - "VIRTUAL_PORT=4000"
       ports:
         - "4000:8080"
       links:
         - nginx-proxy


     nginx-proxy:
       image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
       ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
       volumes:
         - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
       restart: unless-stopped
```

Problem is, when i go to 'my-api-doc.local' in my browser, i receive '502 Bad Gateway' error. When i try 'localhost:4000', it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change nginx manager to 'traefik' docker image. That fixed problem for me. My final docker compose file is following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  apiDoc:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    container_name: "linkit_api_doc"
    volumes:
    - ../../src/server/:/usr/app/
    depends_on:
      - server
    labels:
    - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:linkit-air-api.local"
    - "traefik.port=8080"

  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik  # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker  # Enables the web UI and tells Træfik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"      # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080"  # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
```